# VB.NET How to convert List(of T) with multi-fields to two-dimensional array of String

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, reflection

The List(of T) has n rows with m columns:
FirstName, Lastname, Age, .....

I want to convert the List(of T) to a two-dimensional array of String with size m*n

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I have one List(of Customers) and I want to print this list as a table in PDF using iTextSharp. So iTextSharp uses String Cells, and it is easy for me just loop an array and print cell by cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be happy if i would already have a strongly typed list with all meaningful properties instead of a two dimensional array. However, you *could* use reflection:

```
Dim userType As Type = GetType(User) ' User is the type of your class '
Dim allPublicProperties = userType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.Public)
Dim allUserProperties(userList.Count - 1, allPublicProperties.Length - 1) As Object
For i As Int32 = 0 To userList.Count - 1 ' userList is your List(Of User) '
    Dim user = userList(i)
    For ii As Int32 = 0 To allPublicProperties.Length - 1
        Dim userProp = allPublicProperties(ii)
        allUserProperties(i, ii) = userProp.GetValue(user, Nothing)
    Next
Next
```